# tool for splitting pcap files by TCP connection?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, tcp, pcap

Is there tool to split a packet capture file (in pcap format)  into separate files for each TCP connection ? (other than a home grown shell script which probably needs to run twice over the capture...). Something like wireshark's 'follow TCP stream' but for the command line (I'm afraid wireshark will consume a large amount of memory when displaying a 700 MB packet capture)

I looked at [tcpflow](http://www.circlemud.org/~jelson/software/tcpflow/) but it seems to produce files much larger than the original pcap files and they seem not to be in pcap format.

Comment: The files that result from tcpflow are not pcaps, they are the actual tcp payloads of the tcp streams.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can also use [PcapSplitter](https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus/tree/master/Examples/PcapSplitter) which is part of the [PcapPlusPlus](https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus) package. It does exactly what you need (which is splitting pcap files by TCP or UDP connection), it's multi-platform and it doesn't have a limit on the number of connections in the original file (so you can use it to split a large pcap file containing thousands of connections or even more). The link above is for the source code, but if you want a compiled binary - [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5go4ca778nu4zrm/AABbpDieIPBWQ0sGFNCWU7mza?dl=0) is a link for binaries I made for several platforms

**EDIT:** apparently a new version of PcapPlusPlus was released and it contains PcapSplitter binaries for quite a lot of platforms (Windows, Ubuntu 12.04/14.04, Mac OSX Mavericks/Yosemite/El Captian). I think it's better to use these binaries than the link I previously provided. You can find it [here](https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus/releases/tag/v17.11)

Answer (score 10):

You can use `tcpdump` to extract the portions of the pcap that you want... suppose you're looking for packets in a socket connection between TCP/55777 on one host and TCP/80 on another.  Your source file is `bigfile.pcap`, which is a sniffer dump of many HTTP sessions to the web host in question...

```
tcpdump -r bigfile.pcap -w session.pcap -s0 tcp and port 55777
```

That will pull all the packets going to and from TCP/55777 in `bigfile.pcap` and copy them into `session.pcap`.

Comment: Does `-s0` have any effect when used together with `-r`?

Answer (score 6):

tcpflow is what you want - splits pcaps into one file per TCP session

http://www.circlemud.org/jelson/software/tcpflow/

Comment: as mentioned in the question, I tried it and did not understand why the resulting output files were much larger than the input (pcap) files...

Comment: also tcpflow does not seem to be able to output pcap files.

Answer (score 5):

A bit overkill, but using `tshark` (shipped with `wireshark`), you could do with `zsh`:

```
file=file.pcap
tshark -Tfields -e tcp.stream \
                -e frame.time_epoch \
                -e ip.src \
                -e tcp.srcport \
                -e ip.dst \
                -e tcp.dstport -r $file |
  sort -snu |
  while read -A f; do 
    tshark -r $file -2R "tcp.stream == $f[1]" -w ${(j:-:)f[2,-1]}.pcap
  done
```

Which generates files named like `1509466312.202450000-10.0.0.1-58892-10.0.0.2-80.pcap` (based on the first packet seen for each connection).

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be this tool which might work (I haven't used it personally)

http://www.netresec.com/?page=SplitCap (windows based)

> SplitCap is a free (as in beer) open
>   source pcap file splitter. SplitCap
>   splits one big pcap file into multiple
>   files based on TCP and UDP sessions,
>   one pcap file per session. SplitCap
>   can also be used to split a pcap file
>   into one pcap file per host-pair
>   instead of session.

Answer (score 1):

inspired by @sch here is a bash version:

```
file=cap.pcap
$tshark -Tfields -e tcp.stream \
                -e frame.time_epoch \
                -e ip.src \
                -e tcp.srcport \
                -e ip.dst \
                -e tcp.dstport -r $file |
  sort -snu |
  while read -a f; do 
  [[ "${f[5]}" ]] || continue  # sometimes there is no stream number ex. UDP
  fileout=$(echo ${f[0]}__${f[1]}__${f[2]}__${f[3]}__${f[4]}__${f[5]} | tr -d '\r'  )
    $tshark -r $file -2R "tcp.stream == ${f[0]}" -w "$fileout.pcap"
  done
read
```

the filename will be like that: `stream number__time__source IP__port__destination IP__port.pcap`

`tr -d '\r'`  is for windows users, because tshark in windows output  CR LF.

**Edit**:

this solution with tshark is so slow but sure.
SplitCap is super fast but when there is an error in some packet it crashes, while tshark only inform you about the error but continue :

```
tshark: The file "cap.pcap" appears to have been cut short in the middle of a packet.
```

and finally there is PcapSplitter which is super fast too but it need the winpcap driver, it doesn't work with the npcap driver in windows.

But there is a solution to SplitCap:
using [pcapfix](https://f00l.de/pcapfix/) I can fix the corrupt packets then SplitCap never crashes again. and this is what I m using now, because tshark is so slow in spliting.

and a solution to PcapSplitter I did was injecting the winpcap dll using any method but while we have SplitCap why do it?